# Using ADB or Appium, programmatically remove linked account from Android Settings

Tags: android, facebook, adb, appium

How can I programmatically remove/clear a linked account from an Android device within Android Settings > Accounts? Is this possible with ADB or Appium, or by some other programmatic method?

Android devices typically keep linked accounts for Google or Facebook on a device settings level, not within a single app's cache. I would like to remove these accounts (especially Facebook, which appears to only have one account per device).

The context for the question is in automated testing.

- Removing accounts manually/by hand is not an option.
- I'd prefer not to do it via Appium UI automation; even if Appium could solve this problem on one device, different android devices/OS versions have different settings UI, thus UI automation is not a scalable solution.
- The best, easiest, and most scalable solution would allow me to do an ADB command which could remove the linked account.

Edit:
Here is an unanswered question on Appium forums asking a similar question: https://discuss.appium.io/t/android-how-to-remove-google-accounts-linked-a-device-on-setting-activity/6920

Comment: Have you by any chance found anything?
Either ADB command, or at least a programmatical solution that doesn't involve UI-test framework?

Comment: @MahNas92 No I don't think I ever found a solution, sorry. It also doesn't help that I stopped working on Android automation in the meantime, so the answer probably won't come from me anytime soon :P

Comment: I found something at last! Just added it as answer!

Answer (score 2):

Linked accounts are stored in the database `/data/system_ce/0/accounts_ce.db`, to access it you need root access.

In the case if you have root access you can simply remove the entry of the specified account from the database.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and found something to remove ALL accounts.
Take a look at what AuthenticatorDescription types you are getting if you strictly only want to delete e.g. Google Accounts

```
private void clearAccounts() {
        AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
        AuthenticatorDescription[] authTypes = manager.getAuthenticatorTypes();
        for (AuthenticatorDescription authDesc : authTypes) {
            Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType(authDesc.type);
            if (accounts.length == 0) {
                continue;  // No accounts of this type, continue loop.
            }
            for (final Account account : accounts) {
                manager.removeAccount(account, null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a whitebox solution within the Android app's source code? It looks like [`AccountManager` is an Android API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager). Just noting this because the question was originally asked from an ADB/Appium perspective, so blackbox access.

Comment: This is run against the Android API indeed, but with that said, whitebox vs blackbox doesn't really matter if the aim is simply to remove the accounts with no intention of testing the UI, at least how I was thinking.

Maybe I assumed too much, or only saw it from my perspective, but I am writting UI-tests in need of begining from "a fresh start" (no accounts), and so HOW the accounts are removed, from UI POV, doesn't matter.

But again, from the perspective of UI-testing, I'd say this is a non-UI method, comparable to a ADB-command - neither whitebox nor blackbox...

Comment: Is this solution still valid? Could you describe how you are acquiring the permissions? Specifically, I think this would require the System level ACCOUNT_MANAGER permission. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just try with GET_ACCOUNTS permission on Android 10 device.The accounts,length is 0, but I do login a gmail account.

Comment: Looking at this again, I think this was always System Level, as you said @Sami, I did these when working at a company making Android TV, when I needed to make UI-test to system applications.